# How to display a dataframe with one field through an altair chart?

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I have a dataframe, of this kind, I don't quite understand how to display it in the form of a regular curve graph.

[image]

```
    st.write(data_I)

    model_graph = alt.Chart(data_I).transform_filter(
        size
    ).mark_line().encode(
        x=alt.X('index'),
        y=alt.Y('confirmed:Q',  title='Колличество'),
    ).properties(
        width=820,
        height=500
    ).configure_axis(
        labelFontSize=17,
        titleFontSize=20
    )
    st.altair_chart(model_graph)
```

Accordingly, I do not understand what to indicate on the X axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Including Index Data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#including-index-data) in the Altair docs; briefly, you can start with

```python
alt.Chart(data_I.reset_index())
```

and then the index will be accessible as a normal dataframe column.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me out more than once